# How to exclude Sundays from date range in mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, dayjs

I need to get each user's transactions every three days. I want to know users that don't have up to a certain amount(200) within the three days period, then get the sum of all the transactions for each user. I want to exclude Sunday since transactions are always low on Sundays.

I want to make sure this is done right from the DB because the transactions from each user can run into thousands even millions.

I am using dayjs to manipulate the time but **I am not getting it right**

I have been able to get the three previous date and the current date. The previous date will be the startDate and the current date will be endDate.

But I need to remove if Sunday is in the range and use that to query the database.

This is what I have done what I am not close to fixing it.

**How can I query the transaction table by dateCreated and exclude sundays?**

**schema sample**

```
export const TransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    ref: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userID: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
   
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
   
    commission: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },

    responseDescription: {
        type: String
    },
    authCode: {
        type: Number
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    openingBalance: {
        type: Number
    },
    closingBalance: {
        type: Number
    },
  
   
})
```

method

```
   async getUserRequiredTargetTrans() {
        let now = dayjs();//endDate
        let fromThreeDays = now.subtract('2', 'day')
        let sunday = now.day(0)

        let withOutSunday = now.diff(fromThreeDays);//startDate

        const response = await this.transactionModel.find({ isDeleted: false, dateCreated: { $gte: withOutSunday, $lt: now } })
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it already looks much better. I think seeing a sample of data + expected output might also help, even though I can't myself answer the question anyway. Just want to help you to get an answer, please don't be mad at me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude sundays from date range, you can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator like this:

```
 async getUserRequiredTargetTrans() {
    let from = dayjs();//endDate
    let fromThreeDays = now.subtract('2', 'day')
    const response = await this.transactionModel.find({ isDeleted: false, dateCreated: { $gte: fromThreeDays, $lt: now }, 

    // exculde sunday
     $where: `function() { return this.dateCreated.getDay() !== 0;}`
}  )
```

Comment: NIce answer,why Sunday is 0?

Comment: I tried this but did not return. When I removed the where function, its returned the array of transactions

Comment: @techstack I'm sorry,it should work now since I added backticks to $where value

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `dayjs`, don't know whether you can use it directly. Perhaps you have to use

```
find({ isDeleted: false, dateCreated: { $gte: withOutSunday.toDate(), $lt: now.toDate() } })
```